# Cargar un div con ajax y php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estoy haciendo una chat pero al querer enviar un mensaje se me recarga toda la pagina y no el div, este es una parte del codigo php:

```
    <aside id="chat_derecha_contactos">
    </aside>

    <div id="chatear_contacto">
        <div id="carafeliz_imagen"><img src="carafeliz.svg"></div>
        <div id="pruebaform" onclick="pruebaform()">
            <form id="pruebaform" method="POST">    
                <input id="inputenv"  type="text" name="mensaje" placeholder="Escribe un Mensaje">
                <button  name="enviar" id="botonp" class="prueba4" onclick="Ajax();"><img src="submit.svg" alt="x" style="" onclick="Ajax();"></button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php

            if(isset($_POST['enviar']))
            {
                $nombre = $_SESSION['user'];
                $sms = $_POST['mensaje'];
                $consulta = "INSERT INTO chatusuarios(nombre, mensaje) VALUES ('$nombre', '$sms')";
                $ejecutar = $conexion->query($consulta);
            }

        ?> 
    </div>
```

Este es mi codigo de Ajax:

```
setInterval("Ajax()",500);
function Ajax()
{
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
       {

        document.getElementById('chat_derecha_contactos').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;


       }
   }
xmlhttp.open("GET","chat.php", true);    
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

En el chat.php tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
include "Conexion_chat.php";
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM chatusuarios";
$ejecutar = $conexion->query($consulta);
while($fila = $ejecutar->fetch_array()):
?>
 <div id="globosmensajes" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <span class="large"> <?php echo $fila['nombre'];  ?></span><br>
    <span style="color:black;"> <?php echo $fila['mensaje'];  ?></span><br>
    <span class="fechaSp"> <?php echo fechacorta($fila['fecha']);  ?></span>
 </div>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
```

Comment: Cuando envías formularios, debes usar `preventDefault()` para que la página no se recargue, para ello, la función `Ajax` debe tener un parámetro `event`, y dentro de ella el `preventDefault`... algo así: **`function Ajax(event){ event.preventDefault(); //resto del código }`** Supongo que `chat.php` no es el mismo archivo que contiene el formulario.

Comment: no me funciono, no uso jquery

Comment: Prueba a hacer que la función Ajax() responda siempre false o cambia la llamada por: ` onclick="Ajax(); return false;"  `  Porque generalmente los navegadores ejecutan un submit del formulario al pulsar en el primer botón que exista.

Comment: Lo que te he dicho no tiene nada que ver con jQuery. Tampoco has dicho si estás usando dos archivos distintos o si es el mismo ¿?

Comment: en caso de ajax estoy usando un archivo distinto

Comment: ya vi mi error, se recargaba porque al hacer la consulta insertaba datos a mysql, por eso se recargaba, de todos modos me funciono el prevent default y el return false, gracias